# Image, Text and Link placement with YouTube iframe on same line

Tags: html, css

I've got this page set up and I'm trying to line a YouTube video and a few images with links and text on the same line. I've got a jsfiddle set up so you can see my code and whatnot: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dizzy/NgWNr/)

Here's what I want it to look like basically:
[image]

I want the green "Subscribe" button to go in the green boxed in space as well as the link with image boxed in red to go into the red box empty space.

On jsFiddle, the YouTube video is a bit not-sized then here in this screenshot but don't really worry about that unless it is necessary.

For those who would rather see a live version of the web page sample instead of the jsFiddle small preview, here is a link: [Test Live Page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18844273/test.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/9xQe7/

Here's what I did:

1. Wrapped the image link and "Subscribe" link in a wrapper div (`video-info`) and floated that to the right
2. Removed the margins from that div containing the image link
3. Added an extra div with some content to `video-info` to show that extra content can be added
4. Wrapped the lower text in a div (`video-desc`) and added `clear: both` to keep that text separate from the above elements

Let me know if there's anything else we need to add/change to get at what you want.

Comment: Thank you. This is why I love the StackOverflow community. It is always helpful in any situation and can get to the point without asking questions. Sorry for the newb question, I haven't been into HTML recently. I've been working with C# and C++ on an XNA based game.
Once again, thanks :)

Comment: @user890350 Not a newb question at all! Floats are always tricky. Glad I could help. Any screenshots/video of your upcoming game?